# C++ design: keeping subclasses in a map<string, superclass>

Tags: c++, inheritance, boost, dictionary

I have a ResourceManager class that is supposed to manage resources (images, sounds, etc.), which are mostly Resource objects which implement a stream interface.  I keep them in a `std::map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<Resource> >`.  However, it also needs to be able to manage python resources.  Would it be better design/easier to subclass Resource, adding python functionality and keeping them in the same map, or just to keep python resources in a separate map?

Hopefully I've described enough; thanks in advance.

Comment: It is hard to say in general.  Both approaches are reasonable.  The determining factor is probably how good of an abstraction you can create for your resources.  If you can create a good abstraction so that whenever you use your map you don't need to know whether it is a python resource or not, then having the single map is fine.  Otherwise, keeping two separate maps might keep things cleaner.

Comment: @VaughnCato: So if i was trying to cast `Resource`s to `PythonResource`s, I should probably switch to keeping them in separate maps, right?

Comment: @Aereaux: *either* switch to keep them separate, *or* create a virtual function for each thing you need to do separately for different types of Resource.

Comment: @n.m.:  Thanks, I'll just separate them; they need to be able to do completely different things.